# Multiplying elements of a list in Netlogo starting from a listentry greater than 0

Tags: list, netlogo, multiplication

I want to multiply elements of a list with each other starting from a particular element in a list. Here is a pseudo-code example:

```
set mylist (list 1 2 3 4)
let j 0
while [ j < 4 ] [
  ; set desired_product multiplication of element j with element j+1
]
```

so that it get 1*2*3*4. I know that i can do that with `reduce` but i dont  always want to start with the first element. I sometimes need to calculate only the product starting from the first element (2*3*4) or i only need to calculate the product of element one and two (2*3) for each turtle. For example

```
if age of turtle x = 50 [
   ; start the multiplication from element 1 and stop it before element 3
]
```

so that I get 2*3.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that i can do that with reduce but i dont always want to start with the first element.

The problem is not with `reduce`, then, it is with your list! Luckily, there is an easy way to get only the elements you need from a list: [`sublist`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#subliststring).

> I sometimes need to calculate only the product starting from the first element (2*3*4)

```
print reduce * sublist mylist 1 length mylist
```

> or i only need to calculate the product of element one and two (2*3)

```
print reduce * sublist mylist 1 3
```

As a more general comment: falling back on `while` loops is rarely needed in NetLogo. Whenever you are dealing with lists, there is usually a way to do whatever you need using a combination of basic list primitives like `reduce`, `map`, `filter`, `sublist`, `lput`, etc. Those are less error prone and express intent more clearly.